# Is event sourcing ready for prime time?

Tags: java, architecture, performance, management, event-sourcing

[Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) was popularized by [LMAX](http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html) as a means to provide speed, performance scalability, transparent persistence and transparent live mirroring. Before being rebranded as Event Sourcing, this type of architectural pattern was known as [System Prevalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Prevalence) but yet I was never familiar with this pattern before the LMAX team went public.

Has this pattern proved itself in numerous production systems and therefore even conservative individuals should feel empowered to embrace this pattern or is event sourcing / system prevalence an exotic pattern that is best left for the fearless?

Comment: Event Sourcing has been around for a long time and I believe that LMAX's former CTO (and creator of the Disruptor) has cited several academic and industry papers that he based a good chunk of this on.  I'll ping him and get him to chime in here.

Comment: Look at Axon framework (http://www.axonframework.org) for a seemingly easy way into CQRS. Saying "seemingly" because I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The concepts behind Event Sourcing have been around a long time, and often with other names.  [Tandem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_Computers) computers were built on this idea as was IBMs [IMS TM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Information_Management_System).  IMS TM was developed for the Apollo space program in the 60s and Tandem appeared in the 70s.

Many modern high-performance systems for the financial domain are built on such patterns.  Almost all are custom builds.  Unfortunately no one to my knowledge has offered a product that supports Event Sourcing and CQRS to a suitable standard for production systems.  It is something I've often considered doing having built many such systems over the years.  Just never had the right opportunity.